# AWS Windows EC2 Pull From S3 on Upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a subset of Windows EC2 instances that I would like to continuously copy files to whenever files are uploaded to a specific S3 bucket. Files will be uploaded to this bucket anywhere between once a month to several times a month but will need to be copied to the instances within an hour of upload. EC2 instances will be continually added and removed from this subset of instances. I would like this functionality to be controlled by the EC2 instance so that whenever a new instance is created, it can be configured to pull from this bucket. Ideally, this would be an instantaneous upon upload (vs a cron job running periodically). I have researched AWS Lamba and S3-notifications, and I am unsure if these are the correct methods to use. What solution is best suited to fit this model of copying files?

Comment: Do you want to configure the servers to *pull* files from S3? Or do you want to use something like S3 notifications (possibly in conjunction with Lambda??) to *push* files to the servers? Your question starts off sounding like you want to configure the servers themselves, but then you change gears and mention S3 notifications and Lambda. Also you need to state how often the files change and how often they need to be synced to the servers. Can they be synced once on boot and never again? Does it need to be once an hour? Does they need to be synced within seconds of an update?

Comment: You can create Events in S3 to trigger lot of things. But lamda itself has a run time limit .

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mark, I have edited my post to answer some your questions. I would like this copying to be run by the instance so that I do not have to manage which instances need files to be copied to, but instead this could be configured when the instance is launched. I would assume this would mean that I should pull from the s3 bucket versus having to push to the instance from s3, but if you have any thoughts as to which practice is better that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need "real time" presence of the files, you might think to run [s3 sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) on each instance by a cron job (easy one) or s3-notification->with some lambda works to deliver [EC2 Run Command](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/).

Answer (score 0):

If the instances are in an autoscaling group, you can use aws s3 copy in the user data section of your launch config to accomplish this.

Comment: You don't need an autoscaling group to make use of the User Data feature. That feature is available on all EC2 instances.